# How to give dplyr a SQL query and have it return a remote tbl object?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

Say I have a remote tbl open using dbplyr, and I want to use a SQL query on it (maybe because there's not dbplyr translation for what I want to do), how do I give it such that it returns a remote tbl object?

The `DBI::dbGetQuery()` function allows you to give a query to db, but it returns a data frame on memory, and not an remote tbl object.

For example, say you already have a connection `con` open to a db, you can create a table like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x_df <- expand.grid(A = c('a','b','c'), B = c('d','e','f', 'g','h')) %>% 
  mutate(C = round(rnorm(15), 2))

DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con,
                  name = "x_tbl",
                  value = x_df,
                  overwrite = TRUE)

x_tbl = tbl(con, 'x_tbl')

sql_query <- build_sql('SELECT a, b, c, avg(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS mean_c FROM x_tbl')

y_df <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql_query) # This returns a data frame on memory

y_tbl <- x_tbl %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(mean_c = mean(c))

show_query(y_tbl) # This is a remote tbl object
```

In this case, I could just use `y_tbl`. But there are cases in which the function has not been translated on dbplyr (for example, quantile doesn't work), and I need to use SQL code. But I don't want to collect the result, I want it to create a remote tbl object. Is there a way I can give a SQL query (like with `dbGetQuery()`) but have it return a remote tbl?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, playing with how it works, I think I found a way. You can give a sql query inside the mutate function:

```r
y_tbl <- x_tbl %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(mean_c = sql("avg(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a)"))

show_query(y_tbl) # This is a remote tbl object
```

This will let you give a SQL definition of a variable without having to compute the table too.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there are a collection of standard translations that dbplyr makes from dplyr to SQL. Anything that falls outside this translation is left as is.

For example, `DATEFROMPARTS` is an SQL function but not an R function. I commonly use the following mutate:

```
y_tbl <- x_tbl %>% 
    mutate(new_date = DATEFROMPARTS(year_col, month_col, day_col)
```

And because there is no defined translation from an R function `DATEFROMPARTS` to an SQL function (because the R function does not exist in dplyr) it is left as is.