# Can dplyr for SQL translate == NA to IS NULL in filters?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to query a SQL database, matching on provided arguments.

```
  id <- tbl(conn, "My_Table") %>%
    filter(Elem1 == elem1 & Elem2 == elem2 & Elem3 == elem3) %>%
    select(Id) %>%
    collect()
```

However, it's possible that any of `elem1`, `elem2`, or `elem3` might be NA. Ideally, I'd like the query to translate them to the SQL `IS NULL` statement.

For example, if `elem1` is 1, `elem2` is NA, and `elem3` is 3, I'd like the translated query to be:

```sql
SELECT Id FROM My_Table WHERE Elem1 == 1 AND Elem2 IS NULL AND Elem3 == 3
```

However, my code above converts the where clause to `... AND Elem2 == NULL ...` which obviously doesn't do what I want. Is there a nice way to solve this problem?

Comment: Side note: in SQL `x == NULL` is not the same as `IS NULL x` and equally in R, `x == NA` should be `is.na(x)`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't know until execution time which if any of the three are null, so I don't know whether I want the equality or the null checks ahead of time...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in SQL-server you can bypass this using `COALESCE` like so:

```
filler_value = -1

id <- tbl(conn, "My_Table") %>%
    mutate(Elem1 = COALESCE(Elem1, filler_value),
           Elem2 = COALESCE(Elem2, filler_value),
           Elem3 = COALESCE(Elem3, filler_value)) %>%
    filter(Elem1 == COALESCE(elem1, filler_value),
           Elem2 == COALESCE(elem2, filler_value),
           Elem3 == COALESCE(elem3, filler_value)) %>%
    select(Id) %>%
    collect()
```

Where `filler_value` is chosen so that it is of the same data type (text/numeric/date) as your dataset columns, but is not a value that presently appears in your dataset columns.

The `COALESCE` function returns the first non-null value from its list of arguments. So first we replace `NULL` in the `Elem_` columns with a place holder, and then we replace `NULL` in the `elem_` values with the same placeholder. Hence a standard `==` comparison makes sense.

One of the key ideas here, is that as `COALESCE` does not have an R to SQL translation defined, it gets left when the R code is translated to SQL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348039/how-to-give-dplyr-a-sql-query-and-have-it-return-a-remote-tbl-object) question for more details/an alterantive.