# left_join for tbl: na_matches not working

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, left-join, dbplyr

`left_join` works as expected with NA values on tibbles or data frames, but on tbl it seems it does not match NAs, even with the option na_matches = "na".

### R version and package versions

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
...
other attached packages:
 [1] reprex_0.3.0    dbplyr_1.4.2    lubridate_1.7.4 magrittr_1.5    forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.1     purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1
[10] tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.0   tidyverse_1.2.1
...
```

The following is a reprex with SQLite, but the same happens with PostgreSQL (I actually stumbled upon that problem with a PostgreSQL DB).

### Minimal reprex.

(1) I create 2 data frames, copy them locally to SQLite DB, then load them again as tbl.

```
library(tidyverse)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
df_1 <- tibble(A = c("a", "aa"), B = c("b", "bb"), D = c("d", NA))
df_2 <- tibble(A = c("a", "aa"), C = c("c", "cc"), D = c("d", NA))
copy_to(con, df_1, overwrite = T)
copy_to(con, df_2, overwrite = T)
dt_1 <- tbl(con, "df_1")
dt_2 <- tbl(con, "df_2")

df_1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   A     B     D    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>

df_2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   A     C     D    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     c     d    
#> 2 aa    cc    <NA>

dt_1
#> # Source:   table<df_1> [?? x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
#>   A     B     D    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>

dt_2
#> # Source:   table<df_2> [?? x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
#>   A     C     D    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     c     d    
#> 2 aa    cc    <NA>
```

(2) Then I use `left_join`, first on the data frames, then on the tbls:

```
left_join(df_1, df_2)
#> Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   A     B     D     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d     c    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>  cc

left_join(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#> Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
#>   A     B     D     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d     c    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>  <NA>
```

We can see that the second row last column `C` has the expected `cc` in the case of data frames (by default `na_matches = "na"`) but `<NA>` in the case of tbl even with the explicit option `na_matches = "na"` (which is the default according to the doc).  **This is unexpected**.

### EDIT

Notice that this is the same result as in the case of data frames with `na_matches = "never"`:

```
left_join(df_1, df_2, na_matches = "never")
#> Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   A     B     D     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d     c    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>  <NA>
```

BTW, the title mentions `left_join` because it's the most common join, but same problem arises with `inner_join` (`full_join` is not yet out for data tables), perhaps even more visibly if we keep the `na_matches = "na"` in both:

```
inner_join(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#> Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
#>   A     B     D     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d     c
inner_join(df_1, df_2, na_matches = "na")
#> Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   A     B     D     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b     d     c    
#> 2 aa    bb    <NA>  cc
```

Comment: Read the documentation. na_match doesn't apply to data tables.

Comment: @philipxy can you be more specific? I'm upvoting this just because OP took the what seems an extra mile to show the problem at hand.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik From https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#joins: dplyr 0.7.0 Verbs Joins "[API] xxx_join.tbl_df(na_matches = "never") treats all NA values as different from each other (and from any other value), so that they never match. This corresponds to the behavior of joins for database sources, and of database joins in general. To match NA values, pass na_matches = "na" to the join verbs; this is only supported for data frames." There's no mention of na_match in data.table documentation. However I don't know how clear the situation is--

Comment: @RomanLuštrik --data.table documentation says that tables are frames & can be passed to frame operators. But that may mean, per typical OO semantics, it can they can be operands in calls where the operator name is from a superclass but where the actual operator called is subclass-specific. The data.frame documentaiton quote last comment is as cryptic. I don't know enough about the packages to give a definitive answer. I don't mean to criticize the asker, just inform them. (But they in turn ought to have & give a justification for their expectations.)

Comment: I would never have thought of checking the NEWS file, thanks. :D

Comment: This answer provides a possible work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453060/can-dplyr-for-sql-translate-na-to-is-null-in-filters

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the NEWS link.  My expectation might have been a little naive:  That left_join works on data tables the same way as on data frames.  I understand that SQL is not as flexible as dplyr and that matching NAs might not be as easy in SQL but it would be nice if such differences in behaviour were specified in the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.tbl_df.html).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @Simon.S.A. That trick seems to work:  `left_join(dt_1 %>% mutate(D = COALESCE(D, "z")), dt_2 %>% mutate(D = COALESCE(D, "z")))` works the same for data table and data frame.  One can also use `dt_1 %>% mutate(D = ifelse(is.na(D), "z", D))` etc. instead of `COALESCE` (or `mutate_at` or `mutate_all` if appropriate).  Thanks!

Comment: (@Simon.S.A. &) Habert: SQL `x=y` means x equals y and x is not null & y is not null. For true equality in SQL (with NULL equals NULL) the straightforward expression is `x=y or (x is null & y is null)` so in R `x=y or (is.na(x) & is.na(y))`. PS Yes "left_join works on data tables the same way as on data frames"--the dplyr code says left_join.data.table(x, ...) is as.data.table(left_join.tbl_df(tbl_df(x),...))). But how to explain the row with 2 <NA>s where na_match is not used? Do you have a trace? Do I misunderstand tibbles vs tbl_df vs df?

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the clarification with the SQL meaning of `x = y`.  Also, not sure what you mean by "Do you have a trace?".

Comment: @philipxy I used the term "data frame" for the df_1 and df_2 above (tibble is just a more modern version of data frame) and the term "data table" for dt_1 and dt_2 above.  This is an over-simplification since `class(df_1)` returns `"tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"` and `class(dt_1)` returns `"tbl_SQLiteConnection" "tbl_dbi" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"`.  Anyway, I showed that `left_join` does not work the same way with "data frames" as with "data tables" (as you noticed, removing the `na_matches` option yields the same output: 2 `<NA>`s instead of 1).  But I thought your NEWS link addressed that.

Comment: Re "trace": I wondered if you had an execution stack trace to see what R was actually calling. I see now the dt_N are neither dfs nor dts--does that not make the NEWS & na_match irrelevant?--but rather are of classes with SQL semantics. I guess the C _left_join eventually called via the left_joins knows about those connection table classes.

Comment: @philipxy the NEWS link says `na_matches = "na"` "is only supported for data frames".  Not sure what "data frame" exactly means here.  If it is just class `data.frame`, possibly with `tbl_df`, but excluding `tbl`, then it still seems relevant.  However, I still think it should be clearly specified in the doc.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find any left_joins but .data.frame & .tbl_df. I can't get at your "doc" link. Wait--your "definition" link is to dbplyr--but it's not explicit in your code. I see I used library(tidyverse) at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ with tidyverse 1.2.1 & no dbplyr & apparently just left_join for dt & df in scope plus C++ version. Didn't get any errors on your initialization code & got the same 2 left_join results. Thus I wondered/wonder why SQL semantics for me. debug(left_join) does give a call left_join.tbl_lazy though. PS Why not post an answer incorporating all these comments?

Comment: @phlipxy Thanks for trying my code snippets.  I erased my 2 previous "debug comments" and re-wrote their content a little more intelligibly in the answer post below as you suggested.  In conclusion the `na_matches` behavior is unexpectedly different for data frames than for data tables.  I am ok with that, at least temporarily, since porting the beautiful dplyr package to data tables is still in the making.  But it should be clearly stated in the join verbs documentation to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

To respond to @philipxy ’s request to dig a little further in the left_join process I went on debug mode for `left_join`, first on data tables:

```
debug(left_join)
left_join(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#>  debugging in: left_join(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#>  debug: {
#>      UseMethod("left_join")
#>  }
Browse[2]>  n
#>  debug: UseMethod("left_join")
#>  Browse[2]> n
#>  debugging in: left_join.tbl_lazy(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#>  debug: {
#>      add_op_join(x, y, "left", by = by, sql_on = sql_on, copy = copy,
#>          suffix = suffix, auto_index = auto_index, ...)
#>  }
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: add_op_join(x, y, "left", by = by, sql_on = sql_on, copy = copy,
#>      suffix = suffix, auto_index = auto_index, ...)
Browse[3]> s
#>  debugging in: add_op_join(x, y, "left", by = by, sql_on = sql_on, copy = copy,
#>      suffix = suffix, auto_index = auto_index, ...)
#>  debug: {
#>      if (!is.null(sql_on)) {
#>         by <- list(x = character(0), y = character(0), on = sql(sql_on))
#>      }
#>      else if (identical(type, "full") && identical(by, character())) {
#>          type <- "cross"
#>          by <- list(x = character(0), y = character(0))
#>      }
#>      else {
#>          by <- common_by(by, x, y)
#>      }
#>      y <- auto_copy(x, y, copy = copy, indexes = if (auto_index)
#>          list(by$y))
#>      vars <- join_vars(op_vars(x), op_vars(y), type = type, by = by,
#>          suffix = suffix)
#>      x$ops <- op_double("join", x, y, args = list(vars = vars,
#>          type = type, by = by, suffix = suffix))
#>      x
#>  }
Browse[4]> f
#>  Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#>  exiting from: add_op_join(x, y, "left", by = by, sql_on = sql_on, copy = copy,
#>      suffix = suffix, auto_index = auto_index, ...)
#>  exiting from: left_join.tbl_lazy(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#>  exiting from: left_join(dt_1, dt_2, na_matches = "na")
#>  # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#>  # Database: sqlite 3.29.0 [:memory:]
#>    A     B     D     C
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 a     b     d     c
#>  2 aa    bb    NA    NA
```

We see that `left_join` calls `left_join.tbl_lazy` on data tables with the `na_matches = “na”` option.
However this is followed by a call to `add_op_join` the definition of which does not have any mention of `na_matches`.

Then, by contrast, on data frames:

```
left_join(df_1, df_2)
#>  debugging in: left_join(df_1, df_2)
#>  debug: {
#>      UseMethod("left_join")
#>  }
Browse[2]> n
#>  debug: UseMethod("left_join")
Browse[2]>
#>  debugging in: left_join.tbl_df(df_1, df_2)
#>  debug: {
#>      check_valid_names(tbl_vars(x))
#>      check_valid_names(tbl_vars(y))
#>      by <- common_by(by, x, y)
#>      suffix <- check_suffix(suffix)
#>      na_matches <- check_na_matches(na_matches)
#>      y <- auto_copy(x, y, copy = copy)
#>      vars <- join_vars(tbl_vars(x), tbl_vars(y), by, suffix)
#>      by_x <- vars$idx$x$by
#>      by_y <- vars$idx$y$by
#>      aux_x <- vars$idx$x$aux
#>      aux_y <- vars$idx$y$aux
#>      out <- left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches,
#>          environment())
#>      names(out) <- vars$alias
#>      reconstruct_join(out, x, vars)
#>  }
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: check_valid_names(tbl_vars(x))
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: check_valid_names(tbl_vars(y))
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: by <- common_by(by, x, y)
Browse[3]>
#>  Joining, by = c("A", "D")
#>  debug: suffix <- check_suffix(suffix)
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: na_matches <- check_na_matches(na_matches)
Browse[3]>
#>  debug: y <- auto_copy(x, y, copy = copy)
Browse[3]> na_matches
#>  [1] TRUE
Browse[3]> f
#>  exiting from: left_join.tbl_df(df_1, df_2)
#>  exiting from: left_join(df_1, df_2)
#>  # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>    A     B     D     C
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 a     b     d     c
#>  2 aa    bb    NA    cc
```

We see that `left_join` calls `left_join.tbl_df` on data frames.  Further down we see that `na_matches` is set to `TRUE` before being used as argument in `left_join_impl`.  All this makes sense.

When typing `?left_join.tbl_lazy` the doc returns a local page for `join.tbl_sql {dbplyr}` which states for the unspecified arguments (the `…`):

“Other parameters passed onto methods, for instance, **na_matches** to control how NA values are matched. See `join.tbl_df` for more”.

Following the `join.tbl_df` doc link, it clearly mentions `na_matches`:

"Use 'never' to always treat two NA or NaN values as different, like joins for database sources, similarly to merge(incomparables = FALSE). The default, 'na', always treats two NA or NaN values as equal, like merge(). Users and package authors can change the default behavior by calling pkgconfig::set_config('dplyr::na_matches' = 'never')".

So there seems to be some inconsistency between the doc and the code for data tables.

Also, @philipxy mentioned this [news link](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#joins) where it is stated "To match NA values, pass na_matches = 'na' to the join verbs; **this is only supported for data frames**".  Now the class of dt_1 and df_1 are:

```
class(df_1)
#>  [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(dt_1)
#>  [1] "tbl_SQLiteConnection" "tbl_dbi"              "tbl_sql"
#>  [4] "tbl_lazy"             "tbl"
```

I suppose the term "data frame" refers to classes `data.frame` and `tbl_df`, and what I called "data table" are the other `tbl_*`s including `tbl_sql` and `tbl_lazy`.  So this news link also answers the question.

Still, I think the current documentation for the join verbs is confusing.  It should clearly state:

"**The defaults is `na_matches = 'na'` for data frames and `na_matches = 'never'` (with no other choice) for data tables**".

Hopefully, the choice `na_matches = "na"` will be implemented not too long in the future for data tables.