# Week of year using bigquery / bigrquery and dbplyr? (equivalent of lubridate::week)

Tags: r, google-bigquery, tidyverse, dbplyr, bigrquery

I'm trying to use bigrquery and dbplyr to get the [week of the year that a date corresponds to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439540/how-to-get-week-numbers-from-dates) (i.e. the same as `lubridate::week()`, i.e.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dbplyr)
library(bigrquery)

week("2015-08-11")   
# [1] 32
```

but I am using `bigrquery` and `dbplyr`

## What I've tried so far

Using `lubridate::week()` I see

```
transactions %>% 
  select(item, date) %>% 
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  collect()
Error: Function not found: week at [1:30] [invalidQuery]
```

So I attempted this home made solution

```
transactions %>% 
  select(item, date) %>%
  mutate(week = strftime(date, format = "%V")) %>% 
  collect()

Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword AS at [1:54] [invalidQuery]
In addition: Warning message:
  Named arguments ignored for SQL strftime
```

as well as another (fairly ugly) home made solution

```
transactions %>% 
  select(item, date) %>% 
  mutate(week = as.numeric((as.Date(date) - as.Date(paste0(substr(date, 1, 4), "-01-01"))), units="days") %/% 7) %>% 
  collect()

Error in as.numeric((as.Date(date) - as.Date(paste0(substr(date, 1,  : 
unused argument (units = "days")
```

but I cannot seem to find a way to get the week number using bigquery and dbplyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot seem to find a way to get the week number using bigquery

Looks like you are looking for below BigQuery Standard SQL function

```
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date)
```

You can use WEEK or WEEK(< WEEKDAY>) or ISOWEEK

See more about date part here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract

Comment: `dbplyr` translates from standard `dplyr` commands to database language (in your case BigQuery). No translation for `lubridate::week()` appears to exist because it is not part of the `dplyr` core. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348039/how-to-give-dplyr-a-sql-query-and-have-it-return-a-remote-tbl-object for a way to take advantage of this.

Comment: @Simon.S.A. - i think you meant to comment on question, not on my answer :o) or you can just post your answer